# How to check if condition if property has a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to check with if condition if response has a string , if response has a string then execute the if condition.basically if there is error from server i want to make `$scope.ActiveFile` true.

main.js

```
  $scope.onError = function(e) {
        console.log('Error while uploading attachment', e.XMLHttpRequest.response);

        $scope.errorMessage = JSON.parse(e.XMLHttpRequest.response).techErrorMsg;
        if ($scope.errorMessage >= 1){
        $scope.applyActiveFile = true;
        }
    };
```

response.json

```
Server response: {"errorCode":500,"errorMsg":"Service failed. Please contact administrator.","techErrorMsg":"Sheet : PROCESS_INVENTORY not found in the File"}
```

Comment: `if ($scope.errorMessage)` is enough since this variable doesn't hold a number variable

Comment: if( typeof $scope.errorMessage === 'string' ) {...}  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your specific query this should work

```
if ($scope.errorMessage != null/blank) //whatever suits you
{
  $scope.applyActiveFile = true;
}
```

Now answering what your question heading says - to check if property is string

```
if (typeof response === string)
/*typeof tells the type of operator, it will return number in case of number and  string in case of string*/
{
  $scope.applyActiveFile = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this approach will also work as i said above comment there are alot of ways to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
  for (var i in $scope.errorMessages){
     if (typeof $scope.errorMessages[i] === "string"){
            alert($scope.errorMessages[i]);
     }
 }
```

To test in browser console input:

```
var a = {"errorCode":500,"errorMsg":"Service failed. Please contact administrator.","techErrorMsg":"Sheet : PROCESS_INVENTORY not found in the File","thirdFieldNotString":1};
  for (var i in a){
     if (typeof a[i] === "string"){
        alert('Value is string');                
     }
  };
```

Comment: thanks for the answer there are million ways to achieve it this will also work

Answer (score 1):

As mic4ael said, you could use some condition such as:

```
if ($scope.errorMessage)
    $scope.applyActiveFile = true;
```

You could use some regular expression such as:

```
if ((/^\s*$/).test($scope.errorMessage))
    $scope.applyActiveFile = false;
```

...which would check if the string is empty or has only white spaces and turn your trigger to false. You'd only want to check one or two values with this, though cause it'll be performance-heavy otherwise.

Many other solutions...

Comment: Thanks for explanation that make sense.

Comment: No problem. Try to keep things simple and think of performance :)